# Clear all event handlers using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fetch the mouse position. Everything is great except I can't clear all the events by clicking button using off(). When I click on the button, the message still appears. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;

    $('body').on("click", i, function(e) {
        $('span').text(++i);
        $('h3').append("<p>" + "Mouse Position: " + e.clientX + " , " + e.clientY);
    });

    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("body").off("click", i);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just call `off()` with no parameters, or `off('click')` to remove only click events. Although honestly, I don't see how this is working at all given that you're using a single integer value as a selector. How is that matching anything?

Comment: Why are you passing a number into the `on()` and `off()` methods?

Comment: Use this it might do the thing: `$("body").find("*").off();`